# What's this Pokemon show called?

Tags: pokemon

- A Pokemon flew off to the top of Dicoville

  [image: A Pokemon flew off to the top of Dicoville]
- Some purple light rays are about to shine over a building.

  [image: Some purple light rays are about to shine over a building.]
- Some people are seeing it through glass windows.

  [image: Some people are seeing it through glass windows.]
- There are some windmills near the bottom of the rays turning.

  [image: There are some windmills near the bottom of the rays turning.]

Comment: This question is more suitable in [Movies & TV SE](http://movies.stackexchange.com/), no?

Comment: While this question also applicable to Movies and TV SE, given the type of show and it's originating production, it's perfectly fine for this site as well.

Comment: you could try using google image search

Comment: how did you get that many image without the actual show name ?

Answer (score 11):

This is [Destiny Deoxys](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/Destiny_Deoxys), which is the 2004 movie where Deoxys was one of the main Pokemon. The basic plot is that Deoxys was in a meteorite that crashed in the North Pole. Four years later, Deoxys takes control of a city, by shutting down all of the machines and taking everyone hostage. Ash and his friends need to save the city.

At least some of the screenshots appear in [this trailer](http://www.imdb.com/video/screenplay/vi566231321).